# SQL 'Invalid object name'

Tags: sql

I tried to put a subquery to create a new table in SELECT collect. Here is what I wrote:

```
select 
    f.FacNo, FacFirstName
from 
    Faculty f, 
    (select FacNo from Offering
     where OffTerm = 'FALL' and CourseNo like 'IS%') T
where
    f.FacNo in (select FacNo from T)
```

However, the subquery always raise an error

> Invalid object name 'T'

But, if I moved the subquery to the `WHERE` clause, it works:

```
select 
    FacNo, FacFirstName
from
    Faculty
where
    FacNo in (select FacNo from Offering 
              where OffTerm = 'FALL' and CourseNo like 'IS%')
```

Also, if I change the 'IN' to '=' in where clause, the first error query also works:

```
select 
    f.FacNo, FacFirstName
from
    Faculty f, 
    (select FacNo from Offering
     where OffTerm = 'FALL' and CourseNo like 'IS%') T
where
    f.FacNo = T.FacNo
```

Does that mean that if we create a subquery table in a `SELECT` clause, we can only use '=' about the subquery table in the following query? Please help. Thanks very much!

Comment: Incidentally, there's really never a need for the pre-1992 comma-based join syntax; the modern JOIN...ON syntax is always clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The first query fails because the sub-query T is out of scope for the other sub-query.

But I think this can be solved also by using an `EXISTS`

```
SELECT FacNo, FacFirstName
FROM Faculty AS f
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Offering AS o
    WHERE o.FacNo = f.FacNo
      AND o.OffTerm = 'FALL' 
      AND o.CourseNo LIKE 'IS%'
)
```